# Taking Spaces out of a string and Replacing them with "+"

Tags: python, youtube, urllib2

Im writing this program that searches YouTube for a part of a bigger program

when the user inputs the search phrase it might have spaces but i don't want those spaces i want "+" instead so that the URL works

Here is my Code:

```
import urllib2
x=raw_input("Search: ")
site1 = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s'%x)
y = site1.read()
print y
```

when i input anything that's more than one word it doesn't work because there shouldn't be any spaces in a URL so how can i turn the spaces between words into plus signs

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, `urllib` has `urllib.quote_plus` for that purpose. It will also help to escape everything else that needs escaping:

```
>>> urllib.quote_plus('hello how\'re you?')
'hello+how%27re+you%3F'
```

Comment: This is much better indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the problem:

```
>>> "This is a string".replace(" ", "+")
'This+is+a+string'
```

Comment: thats All i needed i feel dumb Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
x.replace(" ", "+")
```